# How to move back critical folders of my Ubuntu installation?

Tags: file-management, livecd, boot-cd

I messed up with `sudo` moving some critical boot folders in my Ubuntu 12.04 installation.

How can I move these folders back to their original locations? I'd be fine with booting some live system and using the command line.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Ubuntu install disc you can boot to rescue mode. Then you would need to move the folders using the `mv` command:

```
mv /path/to/folder /path/to/original/location
```

Depending on how many folders you moved it might be easier to make a backup of your homedir and do a reinstall though.